# "No Operating System Found" after installing Ubuntu Server on Mac Mini 6,1

Tags: server, system-installation, mac-mini

I'm struggling to install Ubuntu Server on my Mac Mini 6,1. It does boot on the USB stick and the install runs smoothly, but then when I try to boot, I get the message:

> No Operating System Found

I've tried with and without EFI boot partition, setting it as bootable and not. I'm starting to be out of ideas to make it work.

I'd like to install it as the only system.

Answer (score 0):

Try booting the Live USB again, then open a Terminal and type `sudo grub-install /dev/sda`, then reboot.
If you can get the Ubuntu server to boot, then immediately type `sudo update-grub`.

(AFAIK, the `sudo` is unnecessary, as the Live CD/USB's Terminal is Root, but it never hurts to be safe.)

If that doesn't work, you may end up having to do a reinstall. :(
(If it makes you feel any better, I reinstalled my Ubuntu 3 times in less than a week once...)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've tried it but still the same problem... I'm at my 15th time installing ubuntu server at least...  :S

Comment: The message is missing operating system actually, but doesnt change anything

Comment: Okay, so the installation is finished, and the problem occurs when you try to boot Ubuntu? I hate to say this, but... You may have had a slight Internet glitch while downloading. Check the md5Sum of your downloaded file, and compare it with [what it should be](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes). If you don't know how to do this, see [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM). It explains it fairly well.

Comment: Nope, the hash seems to be good. I've tried server version & desktop & I have the same problem with both of them... :S

Comment: btw, I've tried as well recreating the partition table as msdos (because i dont want dual boot) and installing ubuntu after, it still doest work (i get the grey screen with an exclamation mark meaning no system found)...

Comment: Okay try this: use the Desktop installer to install Ubuntu, then, when it asks you what you want to do, choose "Something Else." Then, be sure that you're installing the bootloader to `/dev/sda`, and Ubuntu to an EXT4 filesystem on `/dev/sda1`. _NOTE: NO NUMBER ON THE BOOTLOADER PARTITION: IT'S JUST `/dev/sda`_

Comment: Ok will try as soon as I can. Thanks for your help again. One more question, do i need to create the partition table as MBR (as stated here under single boot : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MactelSupportTeam/AppleIntelInstallation or should I still be using GPT ?

Comment: Hmmm, it looks like you should probably follow the Wiki's instructions. I don't really know, though, as Apple always does something weird with their systems. Following the Wiki's instructions for having a single-boot seems like the best option to me, and it seemed pretty competent when I was looking over it...